# Probability of 1 cookie having a chip = probability of every cooking having a chip?

Tags: probability

Consider $N$ cookies. We distribute chocolate chips to cookies at random. Let $p_i$ be the probability that the i-th cookie has at least 1 chip. Let $q$ be the probability that all cookies have at least 1 chip.

Is $p_i = q$?

If it is, what probability theorem governs this? I believe the answer is they are equal, but I am not sure how to explain it properly.

Comment: For example:  If we distribute a single chip amongst $N>1$ cookies, then $p_i=\frac 1N$ but $q=0$.

Answer (score 0):

$q=p_i^N \neq p_i$ assuming the events of assigning chips to cookies are independent.

Comment: Typo: you presumably mean $\prod_{i=1}^{N}p_i=q$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop I don't think that's a dependent. The distribution is identical. so $\prod_{i=1}^N p_i = p_i^N$

Comment: @user5965026 Why do you think the distribution is identical?

Comment: @AndreasBlass I defined $p_i$ to be the probability that the i-th cookie contains at least 1 chip. By symmetry, they should all be identical.

Comment: @user5965026 The use of $p_i$ rather than simply $p$ was what told me that you were not assuming identical distributions. In your latest comment, where did the assumption of symmetry come from? Shouldn't such assumptions be included in the question?

Comment: @AndreasBlass Symmetry isn't an assumption here, but something that you're supposed to realize within the problem. If you distribution 1 chip to $N$ cookies at random, wouldn't you agree that each cookie will have an equal probability of obtaining that chip? That's where the symmetry is coming from. If you disagree, why do you believe $p_i = p_j$ for $i \neq j$?

Comment: @user5965026 I didn't believe $p_i=p_j$ until you added that hypothesis in your comment; there's nothing in the question to suggest that belief. In fact, the notation $p_i$ suggests the contrary. (There's also nothing in the question that implies all the cookies are the same size, which might suggest that the $p_i$'s are all equal.) In any case, mathematics is about deducing consequences from given hypotheses, not about guessing the intended interpretation of vague hints.